# Meaning and connotations of "these are my pieces"

Tags: meaning

At work, someone came up to me to discuss an internal email I'd sent round the office about some planned changes.

At the end they said to me:

> Well, these are my pieces. I have said them.

...
What?

What was that intended to mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From M-W

> [piece](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/piece)
>   9 : opinion, view • *spoke his piece*

The speaker is saying that they have expressed their opinion(s). I expect *I've said my piece* here, not what the speaker said. I'm guessing the speaker is expressing dissatisfaction, but without further context, it's up to you to determine the speaker's feeling. I also guess they worded it that way to further convey their feeling.

Comment: ah, right. Yes, of course. They were indeed raising concerns (plural, hence "pieces") about the proposed changes. Now that you've prompted me with this, I think the specific intent was "I've said my piece ... and now I don't intend to push it any further, I'll leave you to take my concerns into account and then make a sensible final judgement based on them and on other opinions offered by other employees)

Answer (score -2):

Without knowing their *intention,* it's difficult to say what they meant by that. But, checking the event, I think they wanted to say that what all you had written in the email belonged to them! I mean whatever suggestion, advise, or words you had in your email are originally by them!

Of course, this is *my* way of seeing that!

Comment: No, they said it at the end. See https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/say+piece.